# Why does this index-selecting code not work?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to only return the odd-indexed elements of a list.

I have this code, it compiles, but it give me a run-time error.

here's my code:

```
oddSelect :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
oddSelect []     = []
oddSelect (x:xs) = head (drop 1 (x:xs)) : oddSelect (xs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use recursion:

```
evenSelect :: [a] -> [a]
evenSelect []       = []
evenSelect [x]      = [x]
evenSelect (x:_:xs) = x : evenSelect xs
```

Another solution which I like more:

```
import Data.List.Split

evenSelect :: [a] -> [a]
evenSelect = map head . chunksOf 2
```

Comment: Thanks man. I figured it out that it is exactly this. You are absolutely right. Only thing is I would have the recursive case as: evenSelect (_:x:xs) = x:evenSelect xs. I also changed the name to evenSelect, as opposed to oddSelect.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think that that's a good solution. Mostly, I am usually wary of using `head`.

What I'd do personally is zip the elements with an index, then remove all even numbers (`filter odd`) and then finally get rid of the indexes (`map snd`)

```
oddSelect :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
oddSelect l = map snd $ filter (\(idx,value) -> odd idx) (zip [1..] l)
```

As for your code,
This clause is fine

```
oddSelect []        =[]
```

But the second one needs some work. I've rewritten it for you:

```
oddSelect (x:xs)    =x:oddSelect (drop 1 xs)
```

x is already the first element of the list (not a list by itself) so it can be added to the head of your new list. Now, you want to call your function again recursively, but now you want to snip the first element of the REST of the list, because it is even - so you want to call `drop 1 xs` instead of `drop 1 (x:xs)` which is equivalent of just using `xs`

Comment: it needs to be done recursively and without using lambda and lots of libraries. Only primitive libraries such as head tail, drop, etc.

Comment: I've fixed your solution without lambdas.

Comment: You should always mention any constraints on the solution when you ask the question... I can't guess those things.

Comment: Actually, I have the EXACT SAME function as the one you provided for my even Select, because I considered 0 to be my 1st index and counted it as an even member. So I guess what I am trying to accomplish is to return the 2nd element of the list, skip 1 and return the next. So if you have (1, 2, 3, 4), I would like to obtain (2, 4). And sorry about the misunderstanding above.

Comment: This is quite trivial with only recursion and pattern matching. No `head`, no `drop`, nothing is need, except constructors of list (`:` and `[]`), of course. When a function can be written so simply, I would consider it non-idiomatic to write is using a zip, a filter, and a map. `oddSelect (_:x:xs) = x:oddSelect xs; oddSelect _ = []`.

Comment: This:                                                              evenSelect:: [Integer]->[Integer]
evenSelect _ = []
evenSelect (_:x:xs) = x:evenSelect xs; produces [] at all times. Doesn't matter what I pass to it.

Comment: It works as soon as I change the base case to evenSelect [] = []. However, the problem is that it will only work on even-sized lists. As soon as I pass an odd-based list to it and it produces a runtime error.

Comment: @RumenHristov no, your original function is not exactly the same. You drop the first element, then drop the first element of the tail etc.

Comment: @RumenHristov add a condition for a singleton list, then it will cover the odd-length lists case.

Comment: I just realized that. The same time you wrote it. But thanks anyways

Comment: So it needs to be: evenSelect[] = []. then evenSelect[x] = []. Then evenSelect(_:x:xs) = x:evenSelect xs

Answer (score 0):

`drop 1 (x:xs)` is actually the same as `xs`. If `xs` is empty, `head` must fail. Actually, even if you fix that part, it still won't work, since at this point you're trying to unconditionally drop the first element and continue recursively, which will always return an empty list.

The simple way is:

```
oddSelect = map snd . filter (odd . fst) . zip [1..]
```

But if you want your own recursive function, you still need to pass the current index somewhere or have some other way to drop only every second element.